# How to import certificate in XMPPFrameWork

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I am implementing XMPP framework in my app.I have a certificate in my app bundle sent from server(.p12).How can i import it in my code and how to send them to server for his authentication.

```
  - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender willSecureWithSettings:(NSMutableDictionary *)settings
{
DDLogVerbose(@"%@: %@", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD);

NSString *expectedCertName = [xmppStream.myJID domain];
if (expectedCertName)
{
    [settings setObject:expectedCertName forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
}

if (customCertEvaluation)
{

NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"TestKey" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *pkcs12data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Import .p12 data
CFArrayRef keyref = NULL;
OSStatus sanityCheck = SecPKCS12Import((__bridge CFDataRef)pkcs12data,
                                       (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)[NSDictionary
                                                                  dictionaryWithObject:path
                                                                  forKey:(__bridge id)kSecImportExportPassphrase],
                                       &keyref);
if (sanityCheck != noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Error while importing pkcs12 [%d]", (int)sanityCheck);
} else
    NSLog(@"Success opening p12 certificate.");

// Identity
CFDictionaryRef identityDict = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(keyref, 0);
SecIdentityRef identityRef = (SecIdentityRef)CFDictionaryGetValue(identityDict,
                                                                  kSecImportItemIdentity);

// Cert
SecCertificateRef cert = NULL;
OSStatus status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identityRef, &cert);
if (status)
    NSLog(@"SecIdentityCopyCertificate failed.");

// the certificates array, containing the identity then the root certificate
NSArray *myCerts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(__bridge id)identityRef, (__bridge id)cert, nil];

      NSMutableDictionary *SSLOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [settings setObject:@(YES) forKey:GCDAsyncSocketManuallyEvaluateTrust];//normal @(yes) in set object
    [SSLOptions setObject:myCerts forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates];
   [SSLOptions setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLIsServer];
   [outputStream setProperty:SSLOptions forKey:(__bridge id)kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings];
}
}
```

This is my code it is not working.I am new to this so i don't know if it is correct.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which certificate you are importing..

Comment: .p12 check the question